# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, select, join

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT SUM(A.Precio)AS "Total gastado", B.email FROM ARTICULO_EVENTO A
    JOIN (C.email FROM PEDIDO_ARTICULO_EVENTO C)B
    ON(B.email=A.email)
WHERE B.FechaHora > TO_DATE('20-08-2012', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
GROUP BY (B.email)
ORDER BY SUM(A.Precio) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <=5;
```

ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis. At line 3.

¿Why do i get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, you forgot the select keyword in a subquery and left a ";":

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT SUM(A.Precio)AS "Total gastado", B.email FROM ARTICULO_EVENTO A
    JOIN (select C.email FROM PEDIDO_ARTICULO_EVENTO C)B
    ON(B.email=A.email)
WHERE B.FechaHora > TO_DATE('20-08-2012', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
GROUP BY (B.email)
ORDER BY SUM(A.Precio) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <=5;
```